# How to avoid duplication of code using php & mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create a website which allows a user to create a job which is saved to a database and then all the jobs can be viewed from a different page on the website. I've managed to get this to work but I've had to duplicate all of the MySQL log in set up in PHP. I'd like to avoid this duplication and tried using an autoloader but with no success. Basically the first 5 variables are repeated from a separate page where I'm adding the data into the database and I'd like to avoid this if possible. The code itself works I just feel like there must be a way to avoid repetition here.

```
    <?php
        $server = '192.168.56.2';
        $username = 'student';
        $password = 'student';



        $schema = 'assignment';
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . $schema . ';host=' . $server, $username, $password);

                $file ='section3.php';
                echo 'Last Edited: ' .date('d/m/Y', filemtime($file));
                $results = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM jobs');
                foreach ($results as $row) {
                echo '<p>' . $row['title']."   "  . $row['salary'] ."  ".  $row['location'] ." ". $row['description'].'</p>';
                } 
                ?>
```

Comment: put the code in a single file and use include?

Comment: or put the code in a single file and add the filepath under auto_prepend_file in the php.ini file and restart you php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual approach is to place the database connection data (and usually the code that creates the connection) into a separate file and then `require_once()` that file in each page that needs to connect to the db. eg:

db_connect.php:

```
<?php
    $server = '192.168.56.2';
    $username = 'student';
    $password = 'student';

    $schema = 'assignment';
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . $schema . ';host=' . $server, $username, $password);
```

otherpage.php:

```
<?php
    require_once 'db_connect.php';
    $file ='section3.php';
    echo 'Last Edited: ' .date('d/m/Y', filemtime($file));
    $results = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM jobs');
    foreach ($results as $row) {
    echo '<p>' . $row['title']."   "  . $row['salary'] ."  ".  $row['location'] ." ". $row['description'].'</p>';
    } 
    ?>
```

As usual, I leave error handling as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: That's great thanks for that, I was hoping for a simple answer and got one!

Answer (score 1):

Put your DB credentials into separate php-file and `require_once` it from each script where needed

**db.php**:

```
$server = '192.168.56.2';
$username = 'student';
$password = 'student';
```

**index.php**:

```
require_once('db.php');
$schema = 'assignment';
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . $schema . ';host=' . $server, $username, $password);
// ...
```

Also [RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php) on difference between

- include
- include_once
- require
- require_once

Comment: Thanks for the help really appreciated!